# Rankx function not not working with pivot table

Tags: powerbi

Ranks without pivot table:

[image: Ranks without pivot table]

Ranks not working with pivot:

[image: Ranks not working with pivot]

I am using Power BI.

Rankx working correctly when grouping by Name.

But if I want to apply Rankx on power pivot... I am not getting it to work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far and what specifically is not working

Comment: Sorry for late reply... Actually I wanted to have Ranks on pivot table data. I am facing issue that I cannot put Rankx formula in query edit mode. I can do Rankx with new calculated columns or Measure but not in query edit mode.